# AWS C++ SDK and MSVC2015: How to determine which static libs should be added?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm trying to build simple programm with AWS C++ SDK and MSVC2015:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <aws\core\Aws.h>

int main()
{
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);
    {
        std::cout << "success\n";
    }
    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
    return 0;
}
```

First, I've got linker error about 2 unresolved externals  -`InitAPI` and `ShutdownAPI`. (AWS SDK was build as  static libraries).

I added `aws-cpp-sdk-core.lib` to the "ConfigurationProperties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies". Now these two externals are resolved, but I get 37 new unresolved exernals - supposedly used by added library.

So the question is - how to determine what other libraries I should add? Is there a way to do it automatically in Visual Studio?

Upd. "New" unresolved externals are of these kinds:
BCryptXXX
_imp_HttpXXX
_imp_InternetXXX
_imp_WinHttpXXX

Answer (score 0):

One way to make using the AWS SDK for C++ easier with Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 is to use VCPKG, https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg. It is a package manager and it has the aws-cpp-sdk in its library (though it can take some time to compile).

To use in VC, run `vcpkg integrate install` from the command line in the vcpkg directory and then it will include needed file automatically in the VC IDE.

For a walkthrough, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/09/19/vcpkg-a-tool-to-acquire-and-build-c-open-source-libraries-on-windows/.